# Some (Custom) Cells do not render in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. Most of the cells get drawn correctly. But some cells render for a short period (milliseconds) then the content inside the cell disappear.

For my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have created a unique identifier for each cell for reuse. This is the identifier I use:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

This way I guarantee that using cellForRowAtIndexPath will return the correct cell after scrolling because the UITableView is reusing the correct cell.

**My question is: What could cause a cell to render for a short time then disappear?**
Could it be a dimensions issue (some cells exceed designated space)?

Thanks for any information that could help resolve this problem.

EDIT (code for cell for row) :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
CustomTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell){
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.label.text=@"TEST":
}




return cell;
```

}

Comment: dont use identifier different for each row.Identifier is used for reuse, then if you have different identifiers for each cell then there is no use of using identifiers

Comment: why not? I have a short list. and it does a good job for keeping order when scrolling.

Comment: Send the code for cell for row at index

Comment: just for knowledge, take 1000 cell and use different identifiers for each and see the memory.Then you will find the difference

Comment: I am sure it will make a big difference for large lists. My list will be way smaller than 1000.

Comment: Just for time, change the line     NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"identifier1"];

Comment: I just did. It gave me the same behavior. I am thinking it is an issue of rendering (IB) in setting up the nib file for the cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62250/discussion-between-ramesh-muthe-and-pacemaker).

Comment: You are practically registering cell for use at the moment when TableView already needs to know about it and dequeue it. Register your nib for one identifier somewhere up (in viewDidLoad) and then call that same cell every time. If you want to make sure that the text doesn't get messed up, set text to nil in every call before you set it to the current value for that row.

Comment: I tried it still doesn't work. Do you think that has to do with the cell appearing for a few milliseconds then disappearing?